# How to make flip side of image clickable

Tags: html, css

dear friends I thank you for taking the time, I have four elements which spin on the y axis when hovered over.  They are contained in four divs which themselves are contained in a div wrapper.  I would like to make the back image clickable when i hover over it and I am unsure how to do this.  It seems to me that its not good form to wrap the whole div in an anchor tag which may not even work.  I had originally included a clickable image inside the div but this appeared to me to be also not good form although I suspect at present it might be the only way, I dunno.  You can see my problem here,

[site with CSS flippers](http://arthouse.comlu.com)

I include the portions of the html and the CSS that are pertinent and many thanks for taking the time.

```
<div id="frontflipwrapper"> 
<div class="frontflip3D"> 
<div id="openings_back" class="back_page_flip"><a href="#"></a></div>
<div id="openings" class="front_page_flip"></div>
</div> 
<div class="frontflip3D"> 
<div id="middle_game_back" class="back_page_flip"></div> 
<div id="middle_game"class="front_page_flip"></div> 
</div> 
<div class="frontflip3D"> 
    <div id="end_game_back" class="back_page_flip"></div> 
    <div id="end_game"class="front_page_flip"></div> 
</div>
<div class="frontflip3D"> 
<div id="strategy_back" class="back_page_flip"></div> 
<div id="strategy"class="front_page_flip"></div> 
</div>
</div> 

/* front page flipper*/

#frontflipwrapper{
margin:10px auto;
width:100%;
height:140px;
}

.frontflip3D{ 
    width:100px; 
    height:100px; 
margin:4.2%;
float:left; 
} 
.frontflip3D > .front_page_flip{ 
position:absolute; 
transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 0deg ); 
background:#ccc;
border-radius:4px;  
width:10%; 
height:100px; 
backface-visibility: hidden; 
transition: transform .5s linear 0s; 
} 
.frontflip3D > .back_page_flip{ 
position:absolute; 
transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 180deg ); 
background:#80bfff;
border-radius:4px;  
width:10%; 
height:100px; 
backface-visibility: hidden; 
transition: transform .5s linear 0s; 
} 
.frontflip3D:hover > .front_page_flip{ 
transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( -180deg ); 
} 

.frontflip3D:hover > .back_page_flip{ 
transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 0deg ); 
} 

#openings{
background-image:url(pawn.png)
}

#middle_game{
background-image:url(knight.png)
}
#end_game{
background-image:url(king.png)
}
#strategy{
background-image:url(rook.png)
}

#openings_back{
background-image:url(img/opening_back.png)

}

#middle_game_back{
background-image:url(img/middle_game_back.png)
}

#end_game_back{
background-image:url(img/endgame_back.png)
}

#strategy_back{
background-image:url(img/strategy_back.png)
}

/* end of front page flipper*/
```

Comment: 1. Your demo doesn't work only in Firefox and IE10, for other browsers you will need transform/-ms-transform/-webkit-transform; 2. If you only need the image to be clickable on hover, you could use a onclick function on the back side divs, or jQuery.

Comment: sure thing but as it stands is there no way of doing it with CSS, because once i can do it, its a relatively small matter of making it cross browser compatible :D

Comment: Okay then, to solve that with pure CSS, you only need to add display:block; to your <a> tag and you can then add width and height to it and it will be clickable because it is default an inline element that's why you can't click on it when it has no content. Also a reminder to think of z-index of your divs. They now don't work properly.

Comment: ok if i understand you correctly i can put an empty anchor element <div><a href =""></a></div> in the div tag assign it values, height, width, display:block and it should work?

Comment: YES, just like the structure you had in your first image

Comment: great one! it works awesomely! really thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Idk if this is apart of the problem but there is a     `<div>` that doesn't have a less than sign in the begining    `div>`